# Execute PDO prepared statement with an array containing null values

Tags: php, pdo

I currently have an array that contains values from a form to insert into a database using PDO.

Some of the values are optional fields and will therefore be populated sometimes and `NULL` others.

The table I am inserting into is roughly 50 rows long and I am using the following:

```
$sth = Database::get()->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->_insertTbl
                                 (field1, field2, field3)
                                 VALUES
                                 (:field1, :field2, :field3)");
$sth->execute($dataArr);
```

The `$dataArr` can sometimes contain null values such as this:

```
Array
(
    [field1] => 44
    [field2] => NULL
    [field3] => Jammin
}
```

And other times not:

```
Array
(
    [field1] => 44
    [field2] => Harry
    [field3] => William
}
```

That works normally with fully populated variables as well as empty strings, but doesn't seem to work with some `NULL` values.

Normally, as far as I understand you would use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, however as I am executing the statement with an array is there any way round that, or do I need to list each one individually?

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` doesn't work with bound params in my experience. Just skip the assignment if the value is `NULL`.

I've also replaced `NULL` with empty strings before...

```
$params = array_map(function($param) {
    return is_null($param) ? '' : $param;
}, $params);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bSYCBg).

(Assuming you are lucky enough to be >= PHP 5.3.)

#### Update

Turn your column names and values into an array and join them with `join()`.

This allows you to easily build certain members if required.

Comment: How do you skip binding a value? I currently have the statement listing the rows along with the VALUES in `:value` form

Comment: @lethal Depends a lot on how you write your SQL. Just skip the assignment in the INSERT (either by skipping `column="abc"` or not listing it in the first group inside of parens.

Comment: The issue I had was, for example with `address2` in my db, sometimes it will be NULL and others it will be populated. Hence it would need to be bound as far as I understand?

Comment: @lethalMango If you don't populate it, it will remain as NULL in the database won't it?

Comment: I have updated my original question with a sample array and query format. If you could explain your solution with reference to my update that would be fantastic :)